# User permissions

Tags: mac, terminal, permissions, user

Trying to sort out my file permissions in order not to use `sudo` constantly (what does not work most of the times anyway) to manage my ruby gems and rails installs.

i get permission errors to when creating databases, updating ruby gems, downloading gems etc...

how can i allow my Berzins, Linards user to be an admin when logged in by default?

I am using my admin privilages from GUI and it indicate from the preferences in GUI that my Linards Berzins user is an admin.

I would like to grant the user Linards Berzins an admin rights to manage my rails gems in terminal without any errors or `sudo`.

Command result of `ls -ld` in the directory `Linards:~ Berzins$` is:

`Linards:~ Berzins$ ls -ld
 drwxr-xr-x+ 58 Berzins  staff  1972  8 Apr 21:34 .
 Linards:~ Berzins$`

```
Linards:~ Berzins$ ls -l
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   91 Berzins  staff   3094 20 Apr 20:54 Applications
drwx------+  26 Berzins  staff    884  4 May 22:27 Desktop
-rw-r--r--@   1 Berzins  staff   1708  4 Apr 18:39 Desktop.pem
drwx------@  18 Berzins  staff    612  5 Feb 21:57 Documents
drwx------+  21 Berzins  staff    714  4 May 22:27 Downloads
drwx------@  63 Berzins  staff   2142  3 May 23:09 Google Drive
drwxr-xr-x@  70 Berzins  staff   2380 26 Apr 10:53 Library
-rw-r--r--@   1 Berzins  staff    724  8 Nov  2014 Linards 
Berzins.downsizelicense
drwx------+   4 Berzins  staff    136 17 Nov 12:40 Movies
drwx------+   7 Berzins  staff    238 13 Feb  2016 Music
drwx------+  34 Berzins  staff   1156  6 Dec 11:35 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x+   6 Berzins  staff    204 23 Sep  2015 Public
drwxr-xr-x    4 Berzins  staff    136  5 Apr 07:58 RubymineProjects
drwxr-xr-x    2 Berzins  staff     68  1 Nov  2016 Usenet.nl
drwxr-xr-x    5 Berzins  staff    170  9 Apr  2016 WebstormProjects
drwxr-xr-x   11 Berzins  staff    374 22 Dec 21:45 dbg
drwxr-xr-x  535 Berzins  staff  18190 21 Nov 22:14 node_modules
drwxr-xr-x    3 Berzins  staff    102 26 Sep  2016 sites
drwxr-xr-x    3 Berzins  staff    102 10 Oct  2016 veltaberzina.com
drwxr-xr-x    6 Berzins  staff    204 18 Nov  2015 version_control
```

Plus the result of `sudo dscl . -read /Groups/admin` is:

```
Password:
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
GeneratedUID: ABCDEFAB-CDEF-ABCD-EFAB-CDEF00000050
GroupMembers: FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000000 6F8DC3A8-D4B6-4175-
B24A-1A99756706FA
GroupMembership: root Linards Berzins Linards
Password: *
PrimaryGroupID: 80
RealName: Administrators
RecordName: admin BUILTIN\Administrators
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Groups
SMBSID: S-1-5-32-544
```

Then I tried this:

```
Linards:~ Berzins$ cd ..
Linards:Users Berzins$ cd ..
Linards:/ Berzins$ ls -ld
drwxr-xr-x  42 root  wheel  1496 26 Apr 23:23 .
Linards:/ Berzins$ cd
Linards:~ Berzins$ ls -ld
drwxr-xr-x+ 59 Berzins  staff  2006  2 May 21:20 .
Linards:~ Berzins$
```

Any advice appreciated.

UPDATE, Ran this:

```
Linards:~ Berzins$ dscl . append /Groups/admin GroupMembership Linards
<main> attribute status: eDSPermissionError
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14120 (eDSPermissionError)
```

Comment: your dscl append didn't use sudo privileges.  Is Berzins a member of the `staff` group?

Comment: it is @Josh im trying [this](https://www.itsupportguides.com/knowledge-base/apple-mac-tips/mac-os-unable-to-log-on-ds-error-14987-eundfinederror/), but I think its not much related to my issue